# Gaps at the top and side of navigation bar buttons

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a website and have run into a minor but incredibly infuriating problem.

I'm creating a Navigation bar and the buttons of the navigation bar have a gap between the far left, and top of the screen. In other words, all buttons have a gap from the top and the leftmost button has a gap from the left of the screen.

The relevant parts of my Stylesheet are shown below.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar_base {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(0, 21, 144);
    top: 0px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

.navbar_button {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar_button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(50, 64, 147);
}
```

I suspect it's because I have assigned the class to the list rather then the links, but I'm using MVC5 and adding classes to the `Html.Actionlink()` is cumbersome. I'd like to avoid this solution if possible.

Furthermore I've tried assigning `margin: 0px` and `padding: 0px` on `ul` like so:

```
ul .navbar_button {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

to no avail

Also I am not interested in using Bootstrap at the moment because this is a sort of side project for a specific person and I would like to create something unique for him.

Here is the HTML portion of my code:

```
<div class= "navbar_base">
    <ul>
        <li class="navbar_button"> @Html.ActionLink("MainPage","MainPage") </li>
        <li class="navbar_button"> @Html.ActionLink("About","AboutPage") </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've looked at the following questions as well, but the answers didn't help me.

[Gap at top of page despite margin:0 and padding: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909038/gap-at-top-of-page-despite-margin0-and-padding-0)

[Why does this div have gaps at top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485351/why-does-this-div-have-gaps-at-top-and-bottom)

How do I get rid of the two gaps?

**Note:** I do realize I am still a beginner and MVC may be out of my scope but I have job to do soon and I reckoned the fastest way to learn about how to do MVC is to actually *do* MVC

Comment: Use you browser tools to inspect the actual styles for your elements (for example your `<ul>`and `<li>` elements).

Comment: Yeah I did so, and discovered what the answers sought to fix. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class= "navbar_base">
<ul>
    <li class="navbar_button"> @Html.ActionLink("MainPage","MainPage") </li>
    <li class="navbar_button"> @Html.ActionLink("About","AboutPage") </li>
</ul>
```

By default ul has some margin left properties , you can remove it by

```
      .navbar_base > ul{ margin-left:0px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the margin and padding from the ul too (your attempt to do so removed it from the li)

```css
body, ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar_base {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 21, 144);
  top: 0px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.navbar_button {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar_button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(50, 64, 147);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar_base">
  <ul>
    <li class="navbar_button"> @Html.ActionLink("MainPage","MainPage") </li>
    <li class="navbar_button"> @Html.ActionLink("About","AboutPage") </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, but @Anu 's answer was more specific to the class so I'm going to select his. Thank you though! I didn't know you could use a comma and have one set of specifications apply to everything. :[]