# Bug in navigation bar - Gap from top of viewport

Tags: html, css

I was rearranging the navigation bar to have an image on the left side and the links on the right, and I some how bugged up my navigation bar.

It's only on two pages that this bug occurs, so I thought maybe because I have different CSS files attached to them. I reviewed the code on both, there's nothing with margins or padding except for the body.
The bar is also fixed

I tried [Gaps at the top and side of navigation bar buttons][1], but didn't help.
I'm sorry ahead of time as it's a lot of code, I appreciate your time

```css
 

   * {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }

    .nav-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .nav {
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
      border-radius: 0px;
      border: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
    }

    .item {
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 15px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .submenu {
      display: none;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      align-text: center;
      position: absolute;
      padding-top: 107px;
      padding: 10px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: #2F4F4F;
      color: white;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .submenu li {
      margin-left: 6%;
      width: 19%;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .item.has-children:hover .submenu {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: left;
      font-size: 15px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 80px);
      color: black;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      text-align: center;
    }

    body {
      margin-top: 150px;
      color: #7a9ba6;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    a body {
      color: #90949b;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #415b76;
    }

    .cyan {
      color: cyan;
      background-color: #233656;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }

    .magenta {
      color: magenta;
      background-color: #233656;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }

    .yellow {
      color: yellow;
      background-color: #233656;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }

    .key {
      color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="index.html" style="margin-left: 75px; margin-top: 7px;">
        <img src="../Images/Navigation/Intak Logo 25px High.png" alt="Home" align="left" />
      </a>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="item has-children"><a href="Printing.html">Printing</a>
          <!--  <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
        <li>Banners</li>
        <li>A-Frame</li>
        <li>Menu Boards</li>
        <li>Takeout Menus</li>
        <li>Business Cards</li>
        <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
        <li>Posters</li>
        <li>Envelopes</li>
        <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
        <li>Flyers</li>
        <li>Letterheads</li>
        <li>Brochures</li>
        <li>Vinyl</li>
        <li>NCR Forms</li>
        <li>Catalogues</li>
       </ul> -->
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children"><a href="Graphic Design.html">Graphic Design</a>
          <!--  <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Logo Design</li>
        <li>Ads/Flyers/Promotions</li>
        <li style="text-align: center;">Menu Boards<br>
         (Digital & Boards)</li>
        <li style="text-align: center;">Restaurant Menus<br>
         (Takeout & Dine-In)</li>
       </ul>-->
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children">Chinese Calendars
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="Calendars/Cane Wallscroll Calendars.html">Cane Wallscroll Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Wall Calendars.html">Wall Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Mini Calendars.html">Mini Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Desk Calendars.html">Desk Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Special Desk Calendars.html">Special Desk Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Red Packet.html">Red Packet</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/More.html">More Calendars</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item" style="color: #4D4D4D;">FAQS</li>
        <li class="item"><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <body>

      <h1>What is offset printing?</h1>

      Offset printing refer to lithography in general. Which produce the highest quality output of any printing process available today.<br> Because of the fragility nature of the printing plate used in lithography, the process is best suit for short to medium
      run jobs.

      <h1>What is PMS?</h1>

      Pantone Matching System (PMS) is a standard set of color palette that was created to allow a way to describe a color.<br> For more information, see <a href="www.pantone.com" style="color: #4D4D4D;">www.pantone.com</a>.

      <h1>What is process colors?</h1>

      Process colors are <span class="cyan">Cyan</span>, <span class="magenta">Magenta</span>, <span class="yellow">Yellow</span> and <span class="key">Black</span>.<br> By overlapping dot patterns in those 4 colors, about 70% of all the visible colors can
      be reproduce.

      <h1>What is color matching?</h1>

      Since every monitor, graphic card, printer have their own characteristic when displaying color, the colors may look very different in different system.<br> In order to counter those short coming, color matching software is used to calibrate input/output
      devises like monitor, scanner, printer etc...<br> For more information, see <a href="www.datacolor.com" style="color: #4D4D4D;">www.datacolor.com</a>.

      <h1>How to send graphic files?</h1>

      We accept files in Press Quality PDF format (Hi-Res, CMYK).<br> Make sure you embed all fonts and graphics file you used with your document. A hardcopy print out would be very helpful.
```

```
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276641/gaps-at-the-top-and-side-of-navigation-bar-buttons
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
 

   * {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }

    .nav-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      display: flex;
      top: 0;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .nav {
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
      border-radius: 0px;
      border: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
    }

    .item {
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 15px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .submenu {
      display: none;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      align-text: center;
      position: absolute;
      padding-top: 107px;
      padding: 10px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: #2F4F4F;
      color: white;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .submenu li {
      margin-left: 6%;
      width: 19%;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .item.has-children:hover .submenu {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: left;
      font-size: 15px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 80px);
      color: black;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      text-align: center;
    }

    body {
      margin-top: 150px;
      color: #7a9ba6;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    a body {
      color: #90949b;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #415b76;
    }

    .cyan {
      color: cyan;
      background-color: #233656;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }

    .magenta {
      color: magenta;
      background-color: #233656;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }

    .yellow {
      color: yellow;
      background-color: #233656;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }

    .key {
      color: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px;
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="index.html" style="margin-left: 75px; margin-top: 7px;">
        <img src="../Images/Navigation/Intak Logo 25px High.png" alt="Home" align="left" />
      </a>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="item has-children"><a href="Printing.html">Printing</a>
          <!--  <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
        <li>Banners</li>
        <li>A-Frame</li>
        <li>Menu Boards</li>
        <li>Takeout Menus</li>
        <li>Business Cards</li>
        <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
        <li>Posters</li>
        <li>Envelopes</li>
        <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
        <li>Flyers</li>
        <li>Letterheads</li>
        <li>Brochures</li>
        <li>Vinyl</li>
        <li>NCR Forms</li>
        <li>Catalogues</li>
       </ul> -->
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children"><a href="Graphic Design.html">Graphic Design</a>
          <!--  <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Logo Design</li>
        <li>Ads/Flyers/Promotions</li>
        <li style="text-align: center;">Menu Boards<br>
         (Digital & Boards)</li>
        <li style="text-align: center;">Restaurant Menus<br>
         (Takeout & Dine-In)</li>
       </ul>-->
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children">Chinese Calendars
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="Calendars/Cane Wallscroll Calendars.html">Cane Wallscroll Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Wall Calendars.html">Wall Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Mini Calendars.html">Mini Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Desk Calendars.html">Desk Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Special Desk Calendars.html">Special Desk Calendars</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/Red Packet.html">Red Packet</a></li>
            <li><a href="Calendars/More.html">More Calendars</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item" style="color: #4D4D4D;">FAQS</li>
        <li class="item"><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <body>

      <h1>What is offset printing?</h1>

      Offset printing refer to lithography in general. Which produce the highest quality output of any printing process available today.<br> Because of the fragility nature of the printing plate used in lithography, the process is best suit for short to medium
      run jobs.

      <h1>What is PMS?</h1>

      Pantone Matching System (PMS) is a standard set of color palette that was created to allow a way to describe a color.<br> For more information, see <a href="www.pantone.com" style="color: #4D4D4D;">www.pantone.com</a>.

      <h1>What is process colors?</h1>

      Process colors are <span class="cyan">Cyan</span>, <span class="magenta">Magenta</span>, <span class="yellow">Yellow</span> and <span class="key">Black</span>.<br> By overlapping dot patterns in those 4 colors, about 70% of all the visible colors can
      be reproduce.

      <h1>What is color matching?</h1>

      Since every monitor, graphic card, printer have their own characteristic when displaying color, the colors may look very different in different system.<br> In order to counter those short coming, color matching software is used to calibrate input/output
      devises like monitor, scanner, printer etc...<br> For more information, see <a href="www.datacolor.com" style="color: #4D4D4D;">www.datacolor.com</a>.

      <h1>How to send graphic files?</h1>

      We accept files in Press Quality PDF format (Hi-Res, CMYK).<br> Make sure you embed all fonts and graphics file you used with your document. A hardcopy print out would be very helpful.
```

```
enter code here
```

Just add `top:0` to `.nav-wrapper
Look good here. gap is gone

Answer (score 2):

i can see body with margin-top of 150px;

```
body {
    margin-top: 150px;
    color: #7a9ba6;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

that might be the problem

Comment: but is that not only applied to the body? 
The nav is fixed, with html margins set to 0

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I clearly understand what you want to achieve.

If you want the navigation bar to be fixed at the top all the time. You can probably put `top: 0` to the `.nav-wrapper` which has `position: fixed` otherwise it's going to be set at the same place as its parent which is the `body` that has `margin-top: 150px`

https://codepen.io/krugtep/pen/GLyvLW

Answer (score 1):

The nav is a child of the body, so even with position: fixed; you have to set top: 75px or whatever distance you want the element to be from the top of the page. Otherwise it's affected by the body margin-top.